# Why is "? extends" required for parameter type matching of nested generics?

Tags: java, generics, collections, nested, wildcard

### Question

I understand the reasons that the java compiler will not allow us to treat a collection of type `List<String>` as a `List<Object>`.  When I write a method designed to operate on a list containing any sort of types, I can get around this by writing

```
public void doToList(List<? extends Object> list) {
    ...
}
```

But, suppose that I have nested collections.  Since the above method can be called on an argument of type `List<String>`, I would expect the following method to be callable on an argument of type `List<List<String>>`.

```
public void doToListOfLists(List<List<? extends Object>> list) {
    // generates a compile error when invoked
}
```

However this generates a compile error.  In order to make this method work, I needed to write its parameter as type `List<? extends List<? extends Object>>`.  Why?

---

### Motivation

This seemingly unnecessary requirement has the potential to greatly obfuscate my code.  For example, instead of

```
List<Set<Set<Set<? Object>>>>
```

I find myself needing to write

```
List<? extends Set<? extends Set<? extends Set<? Object>>>>
```

Comment: It's the same exact reason. If you have a `List<ArrayList<...>>`, but view it as a `List<List<...>>`, you can add `LinkedList`s to it and break type safety.

Comment: a `List<Set<String>>` is not a `List<Set<?>>`, because `Set<String> != Set<?>`. For example you can add a `Set<Rope>` to `List<Set<?>>`. However, `Set<String>` is a subtype of `Set<?>`, therefore `List<Set<String>>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Set<?>>`.

Comment: admittedly, this is very cumbersome; there should have been a better language design, considering the extensive eye sore of wildcards in APIs. For now, we are stuck to it :(

Comment: remember, `G<A> <: G<B>` iff `A=B`. ( `<:` means subtype ). `G<A> <: G<? extends B>` iff `A <: B`. Apply that in nested cases.

Comment: @bayou.io Thanks for the explanation.  I see now that I've been misunderstanding of how the `?` wildcard in `? extends` is applied.   I was thinking that `G<A> = G<? extends B>` given that `A <: B`.